# Android - How to show route on a Bitmap from Color info....?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am developing an application in which i am trying to implement indoor navigation(basic route showing). So what i have is a basic floor plan of building floor as an image. I have marked the hallway in red and the store are just boxes. I want to know if it is possible to get the part of the bitmap which is in red(or any specific color) and then draw another route over it...? Also is there any way to calculate the route from this image to a particular point and then show the route...?

This is my image..
[image]

From this i want to draw a route over the red area. Circle is the user's location. Like this :
[image]

Any help is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

you can get each pixel color by this command

```
ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
```

and you can change that specific pixel color like this

```
if(pixel == Color.RED){
   bitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLUE);
}
```